# Mandar datos desde un Adapter (RecyclerView) a una Activity

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview, adapter

Tengo poca experiencia manejando  la herramienta RecyclerView en Android Studio. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar lo agradecería mucho. Gracias!

Planteamiento: 
Tengo una lista de CardView's de Productos, cada tarjeta cuenta con la información básica del producto (nombre, precio y cantidad) y una ImageView en la esquina superior derecha que tiene cargada una foto de "Eliminar de la Lista".

Problema: 
Al momento de eliminar un producto de la lista, quiero tomar el precio y restarlo al monto total. Ya logro eliminar el item de la lista, pero no restar su precio a la suma total.

Requerimiento:
Quiero sacar el precio del producto  al momento de darle click en "Eliminar de la lista" en el Adapter y mandarlo a mi Activity para que realice la respectiva resta.

Aclaro que mi Activity contiene la suma general, y en el Adapter llamo a la ImageView de eliminar y bajo la posición indicada tengo que mandar su precio a la Activity.

Espero haberme explicado. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Cuando desees mandar información a un fragment o activity( en tu caso) desde un listado. Puedes crear un callback. Este callback puede retornar el item que eliminaste a tu activity y como ya tienes el item que fue eliminado entonces también tienes sus propiedades como el precio.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como implementar un callback.

https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Technology-Store-App/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rguzman/techstore/presentation/product/ProductAdapter.java

```
public interface OnListItemClickListener {
   void onListItemClick(Product product, AppCompatImageView productImage);
}
```